# Remove backslashes in string

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my `jsp` page I have  a `dropdown` list with multiple selection , and I store these values in an array of `Strings` using `getParamterValues()` , then I'm converting the array to a String that has this format: `('x','y','z')`. So it can work with the `IN` operator of `SQL server`.

But the problem is that after the `array` is converted into a `String` each element is surrounded with backslashes. Like so: `(\'X\',\'Z\',\'Y\')`.

I have used `String.replaceAll("\\\\", "");` which was working fine in another `Java application`. I am unsure why it doesn't work with my `servlet` solution (web Application).

here is my code :

```
String[] Names = request.getParameterValues("Name");
String Name = "(";
for (int i = 0; i < Names.length; i++) {
    Name += "'".concat(Names[i]).concat("'") + ',';
}
Name = Name.concat(")");
Name = Name.replace(",)", ")");
Name = Name.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

I know that  `Name = Name.replaceAll("\\\\", "");` will remove the backslashes but I don't know why it's not working in the servlet ?!

Is there a problem with values from the `dropdown` list?

Comment: Did you try printing your `Name` to the log before using it in SQL? I think you'll see that it doesn't have any backslashes at all, and that the problem is in the way you use it in SQL. Please [edit] the question and add the part where you use that variable to create an SQL statement. Also note that in Java, variable and method names should start with lowercase (`name`), and only classes, enums and interfaces start with uppercase.

Comment: @RealSkeptic , i know it's printed without backslashes but the dubgger shows that the variable of name =  (/'X/',/'Z/',/'Y/')

Comment: If it's printed without backslashes, and the debugger shows backslashes (by the way - **/** is slash, \ is backslash), then it may be just an issue with the debugger, that escapes single quotes. Print the length of the string - does it or does it not include the slashes?

Comment: i have updated the question , i make a mistake with typing the backslash pleas check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like:

```
String[] names = request.getParameterValues("Name");
StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder("(");
for(int index = 0; index <names.length; index++){
    name.append("'");
    name.append(names[index].replace("\\","").replace("/",""));
    name.append("'");
    name.append(index != names.length -1? "," : ")");
}
String output = name.toString();
```

The [replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method replaces every instance of the sub string, therefore you do not have to use `"\\\\"` unless of course if you **only** want to remove the double slashes and leave the single slashes.

If the problem persists then there are two possible reasons for it.

1. The debugger expresses `'` as `\'`, so there should be no problem when sending the query to the server.
2. The `\` is not actually a slash or backslash but another character that looks like as backslash. You can find which character it is by using `int test = output.charAt(output.length() - 3);` and then check the value of the test variable using the debugger.

Comment: so i will remove this line     names[index] = names[index].replace("\\","");
 ??

Comment: the same result too :(

Comment: i think the dubgger puts a \ for every  single quote ('x','z') before and after every element , do you agree with that ?

Comment: the first one as you said thanks in advance :) , but i have another question   is my string will sent like that ('x','z') to the query to server , btw i need it to be like that SELECT * FROM tableXX where name IN ('x','z')

Comment: @MohamedNagy Doesn't `String query = "SELECT * FROM tableXX where name IN " + output;` work?

Comment: the query string is sent to web service i don;t have the actual query , my task is to prepare the string in the format that i have  explained in the question .

Comment: @MohamedNagy Isn't this just preparing the string?

Comment: i think yes it works fine but i was answering your question about the result of the query , i'm not able to test the result.

Comment: If the server doesn't have an error, it means there was no syntax error, Or if you can access the database from the servlet then you could just try executing the query string.

Comment: @MohamedNagy no problem, and don't forget to upvote :)